# Prove that a set is linear independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

(let matrix  $A_R \in M_{n\times m}(F) $, ($A_R$ is RREF of $A$)

Prove that if you consider the rows of $A_R$ as vectors in $F^m$, then the set of all the rows that are nonzero, in $A_R$, is a Linear independent set.

Comment: What is a "line" of a matrix?

Comment: 1 equation of the system,

Comment: What system?  A matrix by itself is not a system of equations.

Comment: This is the question.

Comment: I don't think the question makes sense as written.  And if I try to interpret it as meaning the nonzero *rows* of the matrix form a linearly independent set, then this statement is false.  Just consider $\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2}$.  There aren't even any $0$ entries in that matrix but the rows don't form a linearly indepedent set.

Comment: My guess is that a "line" is a row, and that the statement is generally false.

Comment: I edited... guys.. if you're here to grill people, I respectfully ask to move on from this thread. I have just started math. thanks.

Comment: I'm not trying to "grill" you.  I've given you the answer.  This statement is false and I provided a counterexample.  There's nothing to prove.

Comment: I edited again.

Comment: By $A_R$ do you mean the RREF of $A$?

Comment: The example you gave is ~ to matrix {1,2}, {0,0}

Comment: I edited again, i'm not yet so familliar with all the abbreviations.

Comment: OK.  Now the easiest way to prove your most recent edit is with induction.  For the base step show that the row rank of a $1\times m$ matrix is the number of nonzero rows.  Then for the inductive step assume the results holds for all RREF matrices with $n$ rows, add one more, and show that it still holds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32364/discussion-between-yves-halimi-and-bye-world).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being asked to show that the non-zero rows of the reduced matrix form a basis of the row-space of $A$. They already span the row space. You are just left with linear independence. If the different non-zero rows are identified as $A_{R\,i}$, you must show that the only way to combine them to get $0$ is with the trivial combination. Imagine you have a combination
\begin{equation}
c_1 A_{R\,1} + c_2 A_{R\,2} + \ldots + c_k A_{R\,k} = 0\;.
\end{equation}
Start with the first row, $A_{R\,1}$, and consider its first non-zero entry (which is a 1) and its position. This corresponds to a pivot in $A_R$. All the other rows have a zero in that position (because $A_R$ is reduced). This means $c_1$ must be zero. Continue in this way until you pass through each vector.